# Can you register an url intent at runtime?

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

What I'm trying to do is allow a user to define the url domains to handle with the app.

So if the user enters "https//www.mydomain.com" the app should handle all links with that domain.  There is also the potential that there might be multiple url it should handle.

So first, is this possible, second, how?  I'm using forms, but I can obviously do this in the platform specific projects.

Also, is this possible in platforms other than Android?

Finally, as a fallback, could this be done as a wildcard "*.somedomain.com" in the app manifest, or code?

Comment: what about this tutorial with firebase?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android#create-a-dynamic-link-programmatically

Comment: Hi Martin! I'm not sure that I understand your question. Are you concerned about `NSAppTransportSecurity`?

Comment: Can you use regular expression to solve your problem?

Comment: I'm just trying to work out how to make an android app handle arbitrary url that a user would "register" in the app at runtime.  The regex would work for the wildcard domain, but ideally it should be able handle ANY url the user enters.

Comment: Technically this is possible. But should also check with Playstore and Appstore guidelines, or else your app can qualify for rejection.

Comment: If you refer to URL schemes, you can't do it in iOS at least. Because, Apple added a rule for URL schemes with iOS 9. You have to define your url schemes in your info.plist before compile.  And you can't change info.plist file at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since url handlers are defined in the manifest, this is not possible. You cannot add handlers for [wildcard subdomains](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html):

> The Digital Asset Links protocol treats subdomains as unique, separate hosts. If your intent filter lists both the www.example.com and mobile.example.com subdomains as hosts, you must host a separate assetlink.json file on each subdomain. For example, an app with the following intent filter declaration would pass verification only if the website owner published valid assetlinks.json files at both https://www.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json and https://mobile.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Answer (score 0):

Basically U can have deep links for your apps.Have a look at the following url.
[enter link description here](http://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/android-deep-linking#3)

[ENabling deep link android](http://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/android-deep-linking#3)